# Cognitive Search requests with API keys generated in Azure console return 401s

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I was previously using a cognitive search API key with no issues. Recently, it expired (I assume due a migration to Azure but it's unclear).

To get a new API key, I took the following steps:

- created an Azure account added the Cognitive Search APIs service
  (with image search, the service I'm interested in)
- selected the
  standard package (1k req/month at $3/month if I recall)
- created the
  service

When I attempt to use the new API key, either through curl,
   my app, or the test console, I receive a 401. I recreated the service
   and the new API key fails as well.

Thanks.

Comment: The *free* Search API keys expire after 90 days. The *paid* API keys will not expire, as long as the subscription is active.  Can you double-check that the API key is in the proper format?  You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/iyxMsW/1

Comment: It is in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few months since you asked this question, but having just had this difficulty myself, I thought I'd share the solution.

If you create an instance of the service in Azure, you can presently create it on a whole host of different regions and it'll create successfully and provide you a key for it. However, if you look at the [Azure Services by Region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/services/), you'll see that most of the Cognitive Services are only actually available in the West US region.

If you go back to the Azure portal, delete your instance and recreate it in the West US region, I expect you'll be more successful.